# How to clever compose generic traits in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, macros, shapeless

Imagine a number of generic services which have different methods and return a monad or several monads.  These services might be composed in a "coarser" service such as in the following example:

```
trait Service1[A,B,M[_]] {

  def get(a:A):Either[Throwable,M[B]]

  def delete(a:A):Either[Throwable,M[B]]


}

trait Query

trait Service2[A,B,M[_]] {

  def get(a:A):Either[Throwable,M[B]]

  def find(q:Query):Either[Throwable,M[B]]

}


trait Service3[A,B,M[_]] {

  def get(a:A):Either[Throwable,M[B]]

}

object Service{

  //type Aux[A,B,M[_],N[_],T[_]] = Service1[A,B,M] with Service2[A,B,N] with Service3[A,B,T]

  trait ServiceFull[A,B,M[_],N[_],T[_]] extends Service1[A,B,M] with Service2[A,B,N] with Service3[A,B,T]

}
```

If you need to provide a syntax to convert the Services into Services with different type B , you could write a method inside each Service (or a Monad instance) and then one for the coarser Service.

Can the same be achieved with less boilerplate, using shapeless or macros for example?